# How to add conditional operator with string in react

Tags: list, reactjs, redux

I'm making a list using React-JS. I'm struggling to sort the data using conditional operator.

- There is a list of friends (with inputs for name and gender).
- Data should be sorted according to gender.
- When you click the 'male' button, only the item with 'male' value should show and the value with 'female' should be hidden.
- When you click the 'female' button, only the item with 'female' value should show and the value with 'male' should be hidden.

I added the conditional operator but it didn't work. The conditional operator with 'string' will work in React?

```
style={{ display : this.state.male && friend.gender == "male" ? "block" : "none" }}
```

**List.js**

```
class FriendList extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            male: false,
            female: false
        }
    }

    maleButton(e) {
        this.setState({
            male: !this.state.male
        });
    }

    femaleButton(e) {
        this.setState({
            female: !this.state.female
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.maleButton.bind(this)}>Male</button>
                <button onClick={this.femaleButton.bind(this)}>Female</button>
                <ul className={styles.friendList}>
                    {
                        this.props.friends.map((friend, index) => {
                            return (
                                <FriendListItem
                                    key={index}
                                    id={index}
                                    name={friend.name}
                                    starred={friend.starred}
                                    gender={friend.gender}
                                    style={{ display : this.state.male && friend.gender == "male" ? "block" : "none" }}
                                    {...this.props.actions} />
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

FriendList.propTypes = {
    friends: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default FriendList;
```

The data will be like this:

```
const initialState = {
    friendsById: [{
        name: 'Theodore Roosevelt',
        starred: true,
        gender: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Abraham Lincoln',
        starred: false,
        gender: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'George Washington',
        starred: false,
        gender: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Hillary Clinton',
        starred: false,
        gender: 'female'
    }]
};
```

Comment: try using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - `style={{ display : \`${this.state.male && friend.gender == "male" ? "block" : "none" }\`}}`

Comment: Please add the code for your `FriendListItem` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe change your approach a little bit and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) results first:

```
this.props.friends
  .filter(friend =>
    this.state.male && friend.gender === 'male' ||
    this.state.female && friend.gender === 'female'
  )
  .map((friend, index) => ...)
```

Unless you need to display both `male` and `female` genders at the same time, another suggestion I give you is to remove *duplication* per se (with both boolean values in state) and store a single **gender** value as string for example. With that, filtering approach becomes even easier to understand:

```
this.props.friends
  .filter(friend => friend.gender === this.state.gender)
  .map((friend, index) => ...)
```

Comment: to add to that, using `index` as the `key` is a bad idea. React will remove and insert items on the list based on the key, and they should be unique. The index merely indicates the position on the list, which changes according to the filtering. A better value for `key` would be the `name` attribute.

Comment: Here `this.state.gender` only 1 value can be stored either male/female.What will happen if both needs to be displayed??

Comment: My suggestion was a bonus only. Whether they will accept  that or not doesn't depend on me :). But yes, in case they want both results the `string` approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter` for that purpose instead of `.map`.For that you can simply do as:

```
{
    this.props.friends.filter((friend, index) => {
        if((this.state.male && friend.male) || (this.state.female && friend.female)) {
            return (
                <FriendListItem
                key={index}
                id={index}
                name={friend.name}
                starred={friend.starred}
                gender={friend.gender}
                style={{ display : "block" }}
                {...this.props.actions} />
            );
        }
    })

}
```